# Reader Hashtag web app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, web-applications, hashtag

I want to develop a web application, you can read hashtag different social networks: twitter, facebook and instagram and print something that kind timeline.

for example this site:

http://hshtags.com/tags/v/holamundo

Someone could help me? some tutorial?

I want to do it with html5, javascript and jquery mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might try [SocialFeed jQuery plugin](http://pavelk2.github.io/social-feed/) which collects info across different social networks by user-ids and hash-tags.